# PHP preg_match image between html tags

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match

I've got an html template like this:

```
    <div class="cont">
    <div class="...">
    <p>...<p>
    <img alt="" class="popup" src="DESIRED IMAGE LINK" style="..." /></p><p>...</p>
    ....
```

And i want to extract "DESIRED IMAGE LINK" inside the "" tag, currently i'm using this:

```
$pattern = '<div class="cont">.*?src=["\']?([^"\']?.*?(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))["\']?/i';
if (preg_match($pattern, $content, $image))
     .....
```

But it doesn't work, the error is:

```
    warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '.'
```

How can i fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is, don't use regular expressions.

```
$contents = <<<EOS
<div class="cont">
    <div class="...">
    <p>...<p>
    <img alt="" class="popup" src="DESIRED IMAGE LINK" style="..." /></p><p>...</p>
EOS;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($contents);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

// get first image inside div.cont
foreach($xp->query('//div[@class="cont"]//img[1]') as $node) {
        // output the src attribute
        echo $node->getAttribute('src'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

See also: [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/domdocument) [`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/domxpath)

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on parsing html try using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) with [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Comment: The DOM is not always X(HT)ML valid. I would strongly advise against this. For simple stuff, regular expressions work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`$pattern = '/<div class="cont">.*?src=["\']?([^"\']?.*?(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))["\']?/i`

You're missing your leading delimiter character `/`.